# How to write a series in sigma notation

Tags: calculus, summation

I'm working through the integration by parts of $(x^k)e^\left( -2x \right)dx$. My teacher wants our final answer in sigma notation.

I'm most of the way there, I have $\sum_{n=0}^{k} -e^\left( -2x \right)e^\left( k-n \right)(?)$

I know my mystery term is going to look like this $\frac{?}{2^\left( n+1\right)}$

And I know my denominator is

$1$ at $n=0$,

$\left( x\right)$ at $n=1$,

$\left( 1\right) \left( x\right) \left( x-1\right) $ at $n=2$,

$\left( 1\right) \left( x\right) \left( x-1\right) \left( x-2\right)$ at $n=3$,

$\left( 1\right) \left( x\right) \left( x-1\right) \left( x-2\right) \left( x-3\right)$ at $n=4$...

So how do I represent this specific sequence with sigma notation?

Answer (score 1):

This is the falling factorial, which can be represented as $\frac{x!}{(x - n)!}$. However, I don't think your integral is correct. The correct answer should be something of the form

$$
\exp(2x)\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{something}{2^{n+1-k}\cdot(something)}
$$

Check your answer :)